# JodaTime version1.2 Calculate days

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to figure out how to calculate how many days there are between 2 dates using joda time 1.2 (no I can not use a newer version). So the Days class doesn't exist yet.

I can do this for the weeks and days

```
(period.getWeeks()*7 + period.getDays());
```

But when it comes to months they all have a different number of days in them so I can't do period.getMonths()*30.

edit:
I can also do

```
(today.getDayOfYear() - oldDate.getDayOfYear());
```

but then there's the problem when the dates are in different years

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Joda Time [source code](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/xref/index.html).  The `daysBetween` method of [Days](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/xref/org/joda/time/Days.html) is defined as:

```
public static Days daysBetween(ReadableInstant start, ReadableInstant end) {
    int amount = BaseSingleFieldPeriod.between(start, end, DurationFieldType.days());
    return Days.days(amount);
}
```

`BaseSingleFieldPeriod`, like Days, is not available in Joda Time 1.2 but, looking at its [source](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/xref/org/joda/time/base/BaseSingleFieldPeriod.html) classes available in 1.2 start to appear:

```
protected static int between(ReadableInstant start, ReadableInstant end, DurationFieldType field) {
    if (start == null || end == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ReadableInstant objects must not be null");
    }
    Chronology chrono = DateTimeUtils.getInstantChronology(start);
    int amount = field.getField(chrono).getDifference(end.getMillis(), start.getMillis());
    return amount;
}
```

All of those classes and methods are available in Joda Time 1.2 so computing days between two instances would be something like:

```
public static int daysBetween(ReadableInstant oldDate, ReadableInstant today) {
    Chronology chrono = DateTimeUtils.getInstantChronology(oldDate);
    int amount = DurationFieldType.days().getField(chrono).getDifference(today.getMillis(), oldDate.getMillis());
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot, also for explaining how to find it